# Using EntityFramework for ODP.NET, why does the following raw SQL command hang on Oracle 12c?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I'm using

- Visual Studio 2015
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 18.3.0
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 18.3.0
- Entity Framework 6.2.0

In a test project.  The following EF based raw SQL command executes on Oracle 11g Express Edition, but fails (more specifically, it hangs as in it seems to not complete execution, but doesn't throw an exception) on Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition.

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
public override void DeleteTestData(FooContext context)
{
    var sql = "delete from FOO.BAR " +
              "where TO_CHAR(REFERENCE) = 'TestStore'";
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
}
```

Surely my raw SQL is invalid.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure why this worked on my local copy of 11g Express Edition and not 12c, but according to [this website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm) the word `REFERENCE` is a reserved word in PL/SQL and shouldn't be used as an identifier.  Fully qualifying the column name in the raw SQL fixed my problem.

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
public override void DeleteTestData(FooContext context)
{
    var sql = "delete from FOO.BAR " +
              "where TO_CHAR(FOO.BAR.REFERENCE) = 'TestStore'";
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
}
```

Comment: I had a similar experience using a column named "COMMENT".  As obvious as this will sound, the moral appears to be to avoid using reserved words as column names.